# OM2M with dotnet core, restAPI, oneM2M

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, onem2m

I am working on a REST API to communicate with one of the server which is communicating using oneM2M architecture. Does anybody have an idea how to decode its JSON format in dotnetcore?

Answer (score 1):

If your program needs to communicate with a oneM2M CSE then you need to implement at least parts of the Service Layer Core Protocol. This is specified in oneM2M's TS-0004. You should also have a look at TS-0001, the Functional Architecture document, which beside of the general architecture, describes the individual resources, their structures and their relationships.

You can find these specifications here: http://www.onem2m.org/technical/published-documents.

If you are new to oneM2M then you definitely want to have a look at the ["Getting Started"](http://www.onem2m.org/developers-corner/documentation/getting-started) pages and the [Application Developer Guide](http://www.onem2m.org/application-developer-guide).